# How to malloc an array in a function, then realloc it

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I want to pass an array pointer to a function, then malloc and realloc it. The function end, but after I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error before returning to the main.

I'm not too familiar with C pointers, I used mainly C++ for my codes, don't know how to use pointers as references.

Main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

int main(){
int A[]={1,2,4,5,7};
int B[]={1,2,3,4,6,8};
int *C=NULL;
int k=0;
egyesit(A,B,C,5,6,&k);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", C[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
return 0;
```

Header:

```
void egyesit(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n,int m,int *k);
```

Function in a different c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void egyesit(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int m, int *k)
{
    int i, j;
    C = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    *k = n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
        C[i] = A[i];
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < *k; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", C[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    int ok;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        ok = 1;
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < *k; j++)
        {
            if (C[j] == B[i])
            {
                ok = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ok == 1)
        {
            *k=*k+1;
            C = (int *)realloc(C, *k * sizeof(int));
            C[*k - 1] = B[i];
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < *k; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", C[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `egyesit(A,B,C,5,6,&k);` gives a copy of the _pointer_ `C` to `egyesit()`.  Changing `C` within `egyesit()` (as in `C = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));`) will not affect the `C` in the calling code.  Consider passing the _address_ of `C`, just like code pass in the address of `k`.

Comment: Ok, how can I modify C from the calling code? I need to use **C, and &C in the main?

Comment: Looks about right.  Try it and see.  Be sure to have all compiler warnings enabled to save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allocate `malloc` or `realloc` momory for `C` you have to pass its address to the function. So your function should be:

```
void egyesit(int *A, int *B, int **C, int n,int m,int *k)
```

otherwise the pointer allocated in `egyesit` will not be set in the variable`C` declared in `main`.

So your function becomes like this:

```
void egyesit(int *A, int *B, int **C, int n, int m, int *k)
{
    int i, j;
    *C = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    *k = n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
        (*C)[i] = A[i];
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < *k; i++) {
        printf("%d ", (*C)[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    int ok;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        ok = 1;
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < *k; j++) {
            if ((*C)[j] == B[i]) {
                ok = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ok == 1) {
            *k = *k + 1;
            *C = (int *)realloc(*C, *k * sizeof(int));
            (*C)[*k - 1] = B[i];
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < *k; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *C[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And then you call it from `main` in this way:

```
egyesit(A, B, &C, 5, 6, &k);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just return a pointer to the memory allocated in the function  `eyesgit()` as in

```
int *egyesit(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int m, int *k)
{
    int i, j;
    C = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    ....
    ....
    ....


    return C;
}
```

and in `main()`,

```
C=egyesit(A,B,C,5,6,&k);
```

But don't forget to deallocate the memory once you are done using it like

```
free(C);
```

---

You need not explicitly cast the return value of `malloc()`. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) post.

`malloc()` and `realloc()` returns `NULL` if there some error like insufficient memory. You may want to check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault is in your function egyesit in the first for loop

```
*C[i] = A[i];
```

This is because you allocated variable C like this

```
*C = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

C is pointer on pointer on int... int **C

So you should first allocate memory like this

```
C =(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*));
```

After that, you allocate memory for the array of type int on which C is pointing

```
//*C meaning you are dereferencig on what C is pointing, and allocate memory for that
*C=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n));
```

This is how it should look like

```
 void egyesit(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int m, int *k)
 {
     int i, j;
     C = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*));
     *C = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
     *k = n;
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
         printf("%d ", A[i]);
         C[i] = A[i];
     }
     printf("\n");
     //and the rest of the function
```